# My camera supporting UVC can't be used by apps in Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, webcam, gpu-driver

## The problem

Hi,
I have a Sunplus USB Camera (Siri A9 UVC) and I'm trying to use it as a PC webcam.
No matter what I try, it is visible in v4l2 however breaks apps using it. Ex., Cheese stalls when I switch to the USB camera.

As a test, i used fswebcam to take a picture. It stalls for a while, then outputs this:

```
karol@karol-hp2:~$ fswebcam --jpeg 85 -d /dev/video2 web-cam-shot.jpg
--- Opening /dev/video2...
Trying source module v4l2...
/dev/video2 opened.
No input was specified, using the first. (here stalls)
Unable to find a compatible palette format.
```

---

On Win10 (on the same laptop), the camera works without any problems. However here, not only does it break apps using it, but it also  breaks *pulseaudio*. When the camera is plugged in, all my audio devices disappear from settings.

#### System

I'm using *Ubuntu 21.04*;
Kernel version - *5.11.0-34-generic*

## Device / Driver specifications:

---

USB device(`lsusb`):

```
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04fc:6333 Sunplus Technology Co., Ltd Siri A9 UVC chipset
```

Hardware specs(`lshf`):

```
*-usb:1
                   description: Video
                   product: Mass Storage
                   vendor: iCatchtek Co Ltd
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: usb@1:2
                   version: 1.00
                   serial: 01.00.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=snd-usb-audio maxpower=100mA speed=480Mbit/s
```

v4l2 devices (`v4l2-ctl --list-devices`):

```
'OBS (platform:v4l2loopback-000):
    /dev/video13

Mass Storage (usb-0000:00:14.0-2):
    /dev/video2
    /dev/video3
    /dev/media1

HP Wide Vision HD Camera: HP Wi (usb-0000:00:14.0-5):
    /dev/video0
    /dev/video1
    /dev/media0
```

Finally, v4l2 camera details (`v4l2-ctl -d 2 -D`):

```
Driver Info:
    Driver name      : uvcvideo
    Card type        : Mass Storage
    Bus info         : usb-0000:00:14.0-2
    Driver version   : 5.11.22
    Capabilities     : 0x84a00001
        Video Capture
        Metadata Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
        Device Capabilities
    Device Caps      : 0x04200001
        Video Capture
        Streaming
        Extended Pix Format
Media Driver Info:
    Driver name      : uvcvideo
    Model            : Mass Storage
    Serial           : 01.00.00
    Bus info         : usb-0000:00:14.0-2
    Media version    : 5.11.22
    Hardware revision: 0x00000100 (256)
    Driver version   : 5.11.22
Interface Info:
    ID               : 0x03000002
    Type             : V4L Video
Entity Info:
    ID               : 0x00000001 (1)
    Name             : Mass Storage
    Function         : V4L2 I/O
    Flags         : default
    Pad 0x01000007   : 0: Sink
      Link 0x02000010: from remote pad 0x100000a of entity 'Extension 3': Data, Enabled, Immutable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
device="/dev/whatever"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, **but there is one more step.**

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the main cause of the problem. I checked my groups, and `ls -la /dev`; everything chcked out. I even changed my device's permissions to 777 - Cheese still kept freezing.  Somehow though, two days ago it worked....