# Howto Scan with HP ENVY 6430e printer on USB port 22.04 OS

Tags: usb, 22.04, hp, scanner

I have installed HPilp multiple times without success. I checked the page by page step by step that is on the HP Linux site and I have been doing exactly the same steps.  The support people on the site are unable to suggest a solution. The printer works and scans under Windows 10.  I have installed ipp-usb several times and it does not scan under that either.
Has anyone been successful in scanning with this printer ? It is a pain having to duel boot into Windows to scan a page. HELP !  Bazz

Comment: In Linux, "printing" and "scanning" are two different systems. `CUPS` (Common Unix Printing System) handles printers. `man -k cups`. Scanning is done by `SANE` (Scanner Access Now Easy) `man -k sane`. Scanning might benefit from my answer (https://askubuntu.com/questions/1364559/my-camera-supporting-uvc-cant-be-used-by-apps-in-ubuntu/1364578#1364578).

Comment: I suspect that the HP software just does not work with the scanner in Linux. Because it also does not work with the scanner using ipp-usb I think it maybe a printer hardware or firmware problem. Can anyone suggest a different printer-scanner program ? Printer is HP  ENVY 6430e.

Comment: Read `man sane`. It says, in part, `hp
The SANE hp backend provides access to Hewlett-Packard ScanJet scanners which support SCL (Scanner Control Language by HP). See sane-hp(5) for details`. Read `man sane-hp`. You are wasting your time trying to scan with printer software.

Comment: I used sane-find-scanner and one part of response suggested permissions problem. I listed ll -l and all the files are root.

Comment: When trying to scan it came up with a statement to download a file from the HP Linux site. This was not a new hplip file as it just installed on its own and lo & behold it scanned.

Answer (score 0):

Having a HP Envy 5534 and Ubuntu 20.04, I simply followed the steps outlined here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-networked-hp-printer-and-scanner-on-ubuntu-linux/, and it worked out very simply with the basic configuration:

```
sudo apt install hplip hplip-gui

## configure with GUI:
hp-setup

## scan with GUI:
hp-toolbox
```